# Magento 2 Multi store with Separate IPs

Tags: magento2

We are getting ready to open a second store on one Magento 2.3 installation. I wonder if anyone had an experience with having 2 stores on the same installation but with different IP addresses.

We need to achieve this for SEO purpose. Both stores will be selling similar items therefore content will be similar but not the same.

Do you know how it can be achieved?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

**single server**

add IP address to your server, add DNS record for second store, configure vhost, point domain to magento webroot, use magento store code MAGE_RUN_CODE

**multiple servers**

the same but make sure you need centralized database, media, cache, sessions, and sync magento files between servers.

read something here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/multi-site/ms_over.html